# Plone 4 : Broken Product. Missing Dependency Error

Tags: python, plone

I am working on a product. However, when I try to install it, I see the error below on the control panel, hence I cannot install/Activate it.

```
Some products were found to have errors when compiling the install file.

my.package

Error Type
    Missing dependency
Error Value
    profile-collective.portlet.explore:default
```

This even after running buildout and not showing any errors. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GenericSetup install profile lists a dependency that's not available to GenericSetup. Either remove the dependency from your profile's metadata.xml or install [`collective.portlet.explore`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.portlet.explore) into your buildout.

Comment: Or also list the dependency in setup.py of your addon.